# How to deploy external webapp in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

Could anyone answer my question, please?

I'd like to deploy a web application folder

```
C:\app\myapp
```

to Tomcat6.x instead of having a copy under

```
%TOMCAT_HOME%\webapps
```

Which configuration is required on tomcat server?

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should create a `myapp.xml` file for this app and place it in `%TOMCAT_HOME%\conf\Catalina\localhost`.

The file looks something like this:

```
<Context displayName="myapp" 
     docBase="C:/app/myapp"
     path="/myapp"
     reloadable="true" />
```

Comment: That works. Thanks.

Just to be more precise. context.xml should be myappname.xml, then you will be able to use http://localhost/myappname instead of http://localhost/context

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\app\myApp] is not valid
What could be the reason for this error

Comment: Either use forward slashes or double `\\\` backslashes for paths in Windows.