# Deploy web application other than webapp folder in apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7

I want to deploy web application in directory(e.g \Users\username\myapps\app1) other than webapps folder.

I know to how to change "appBase" other than webapps by setting "appBase" attribute in "host" tag in server.xml in conf directory.

But problem is, I don't want to change whole webapps directory, I just want to deploy one application not in webapps directory.

Comment: your question was answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661166/how-to-deploy-external-webapp-in-tomcat

Comment: thanks radai for quick response. let me check it & apply it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy external webapp in tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661166/how-to-deploy-external-webapp-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `context.xml` file placed in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directory.

- `enginename` -> `server.xml` - `Server/Service/`[`Engine[@name]`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/engine.html) Default is `Catalina`.
- `hostname` -> `server.xml` - `Server/Service/Engine`[`Host[@name]`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html) Default is `localhost`.

You can specify the absolute path or relative path in the `docBase` attribute.

```
<Context docBase="/Users/username/myapps/app1">
</Context>
```

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

PS (from the tomcat doc):

> **It is NOT recommended to place  elements directly in the server.xml file.** This is because it makes modifying the **Context** configuration more invasive since the main `conf/server.xml` file **cannot be reloaded without restarting** Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks link. I have already followed answer of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661166/how-to-deploy-external-webapp-in-tomcat" question.