# Application will not run from disc

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a web application and I would like to run it from a disc. So, in order to do this, I have created an .iso file from it and then configured tomcat to run it from there using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661166/how-to-deploy-external-webapp-in-tomcat). But for some reason I get this exception:

```
19:27:43.483 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469) ~[spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) ~[spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) ~[spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:663) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1642) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

So, obviously, the application is not being deployed.

Now here is the really funny part: I have the EXACT same application somewhere on my hard disk. If I change the myapp.xml file(see link above) to point to the application on my hard disk, everything runs perfect.

Why am I getting this really strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a lot of debugging, finding almost nothing. In the end, however less probable, nearly impossible, it seemed, I went with the only idea remaining - testing the tool used for creating the iso files.

Apparently there is some sort of issue with [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/). It is free, I received some recommendations for using it, but apparently there is some problem with it.

I would suggest thinking twice about using it.